# retrieving data from a server and processing calculations

Tags: python, sockets, server, encode

My code is supposed to connect to the 37.59.31.202 server on port 2000 using the socket module. I then need to send the results of the 100 calculations sent by the server over the connection. My rather crude code should work but I get an error at the end when I try to send responses to the server and the string 'result' has to be encoded to be sent correctly.

```
import socket
import time

ip_address = "37.59.31.202"
port = 2000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((ip_address, port))
    print("\nconnected")
    time.sleep(1)

    response = s.recv(1024)
    print(response.decode("utf-8"))
    print("\nresponse received")
    time.sleep(1)

    a = input()

    s.sendall(b"1\n")

    for i in range(100):
        response = s.recv(1024)
        rep = response.decode("utf-8")
        print(rep)

        a = input()
        response = s.recv(1024)
        rep = response.decode("utf-8")
        print(rep)

        calcul=""

        for x in rep:
            if x.isdigit():
                calcul += x
            elif x in ("-", "+", "/", "*"):
                calcul += x            

        result = eval(calcul)
        result = str(result)
        s.sendall(b""+result.encode(encoding="ascii")+"\n")
        print("response %s sent" % result)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I haven't found anything of value in my case on the internet, which is why I'm asking here. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "I get an error".  What error?  Post the full traceback.  What response is the server expecting?  You have to know the communication protocol.  Do you have the server code as well?

Comment: If you are using `sleep` and expecting `recv` to receive exactly one complete "response", you aren't using TCP correctly.  It is a byte streaming protocol.  A `recv(n)` will receive 1-n bytes which could be a partial response or more than one (possiblely partial) response.  Typically you buffer received data and extract complete responses according to a protocol.  A protocol could be, for example, to send the size of the response followed by the response, or all responses are terminated with a newline.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Here is the error i got, and if I remove the sleep function, it does the same thing.  : 

s.sendall(b"" + result.encode(encoding="ascii") + "\n")
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: Use `b"\n"`.  You also don't need `b""`.  Prepending an empty byte string does nothing.  This is just a typo if that's your only error.  But you still aren't using TCP correctly.  `sleep` should never be needed and you need buffer the response and extract complete messages.  The protocol seems to be newline-terminated, so buffer and read whole lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to encode the result with utf-8 and not ascii and to not write '\n' after the expression. Have a nice day everyone and thank you